# \hfill doesn't work between minipages

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align, minipage

I'm hoping to achieve something like this:
[image]
hopefully

- height of "large text" is twice the height of "small text".
- "small text 1" and "small text 2" should be right aligned.

I implemented with 3 minipage (1 for "large text" and 2 for "small text"), only to get

[image]

I have 2 questions regarding my code:

- why `\hfill` doesn't work between mini pages?
- Is there a way to align "small text 1" with the upper of "large text" and align "small text 2" with the bottom of "large text"? Should I insert a `\vfill` between 2 mini pages containing "small text"?

```
\begin{minipage}[t][2\baselineskip]{0.7\textwidth}
    {\LARGE large Text}
\end{minipage}%
{\hspace*{0pt}{\hfill}%
\begin{minipage}[t][2\baselineskip]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}[t][1\baselineskip]{0.5\textwidth}
    {\hfill} small text 1
    \end{minipage}\\
    \begin{minipage}[t][1\baselineskip]{0.5\textwidth}
    {\hfill} small text 2
    \end{minipage}\\
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: And you need to be careful with your line endings you will need some `%` (remember line breaks are turned into spaces)

Comment: @daleif Just update as you said but it didn't change.

Comment: Use `\raggedleft` instead of the `\hfill` inside (a rule of thumb: `\hfill` needs something to push against, here there is nothing). Remove `{\hspace*{0pt}{\hfill}%`, it is irrelevant

Comment: I'd also use `[b]` not `[t]` as it alignes baselines not the top of the contents

Comment: Also the width of your boxes are wrong

Comment: @daleif Could you post a full answer?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
{\fontsize{2\baselineskip}{0pt}\selectfont large Text\par}
\vspace{2pt}% interlineskip
small text 3
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}\raggedleft
small text 1\\
small text 2\\
small text 3
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this relies on .02\textwidth  being bigger than an inter-word space in the current font, otherwise you will get one minipage above the other not side by side. also the minipages are indented by `\parindent` (both these issues are masked due to standalone class)

Answer (score 3):

You have no `\hfill` between minipages.

There's a much simpler solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe} % to show page boundaries

\begin{document}

\noindent
{\Huge Large text}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}} small text 1 \\ small text 2 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is something to play with, I've added some lines so one can see the alignment. The sizes used are a bit of a fluke. The only thing we know for certain for the right part is the distance between the two baselines as we set it as the second arg of the font size of that box, the rest will often be some hand adjustment.

```
% all font sizes
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=0.9in,
    bottom=0.9in,
    left=2.4in,
    right=2.4in,
}


%\usepackage{showframe}
%\setlength\parindent{0in}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\hl{\rlap{\kern-10cm\color{red}\rule{30cm}{0.1pt}}}
\newcommand\hr{\rlap{%
    \kern10cm%
    \llap{%
      \color{red}%
      \rule{30cm}{0.1pt}%
%      \raisebox{4pt}[0pt][0pt]{\rule{30cm}{0.1pt}}%
    }%
    \llap{%
      \color{red}%
      \raisebox{2.8mm}[0pt][0pt]{\rule{30cm}{0.1pt}}%
    }%
  }}



% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

\sffamily


\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b][2\baselineskip]{0.7\textwidth}
  \fontsize{10mm}{12mm}\selectfont
  large Text\hl
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b][2\baselineskip]{0.25\textwidth}
  \fontsize{4mm}{4mm}\selectfont
  \begin{minipage}[b][1\baselineskip]{\linewidth}
    \raggedleft
    Small text 1\hr
    \end{minipage}\\
    \begin{minipage}[b][1\baselineskip]{\linewidth}
    \raggedleft
    Small text 2
    \end{minipage}%
\end{minipage}%

\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{3mm}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An XY question? Instead of messing with minipages, why not a simple table?

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}   
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \multirow{2}{*}{\huge Large text}  & small text \\
                                     & small text \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```